# How do I duplicate a gist?

Tags: github, gist

I have a gist which is managed by an IDE extension. Now I want to have two different setups, starting with the current setup as base. How do I duplicate my existing gist? There doesn't seem to be any relevant option on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gists are basically git repositories with all files at root directory. Unfortunately there is no way to easily duplicate a gist through Github UI. We need to go through these steps:

1. Create the destination gist: Add random stuff as part of it, we just need a gist id.
2. Clone source gist & force push to destination gist:

   ```sh
   cd /tmp
   git clone git@gist.github.com:<source-gist-id>.git source-gist
   cd source-gist
   git push --force git@gist.github.com:<destination-gist-id>.git
   ```